# Crash when accessing nested completion block -- EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, exc-bad-access

I've found a reliable crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` while implementing a cache on my app. I've recreated the situation in a new project in about ~50 lines of code with 2 pods (Alamofire, HanekeSwift), and it crashes every time.

All I am doing is in my ViewController, calling a cache get:

```
CachingManager.sharedInstance.fetchAllThings({
    result in
    // result should be an array of objects
    print(result)
})
```

and the CachingManager's `fetchAllThings` method is:

```
func fetchAllThings(completion: ([AnyObject] -> Void)?) {

    let fetcher = CustomFetcher<JSON>(key: "HELLO")

    fetcher.fetch(failure: {
        error in
        print(error)
        }, success: {
            json in
            completion?(json.array)
    })
}
```

Now, the `CustomFetcher` found above is implemented as such:

```
override func fetch(failure fail: ((NSError?) -> ()), success succeed: (JSON) -> ()) {
    let endpoint = "www.google.com"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, endpoint, parameters: nil, encoding: .URL, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON {
            (data) -> Void in
            self.onReceiveData(data.data!, failure: fail, success: succeed)
    }
}

private func onReceiveData(data: NSData, failure: ((NSError?) -> ()), success: (JSON) -> ()) {
    success(JSON.Array(["HI"]))   <--- CRASH HAPPENS HERE
}
```

I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when trying to run the `success` block in my `onReceiveData`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a Swift issue? Is this an issue with the pods I'm using?

For reference, linked is a project with the code above that will crash on launch every time if that helps anyone debug this.

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/coolbnjmn/TestHaneke)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the use of a Custom fetcher is not that clear in the Haneke docs. With the above `fetchAllThings` method, I was trying to fetch directly from the `CustomFetcher`, which was causing the bad access (that is not it's intended use, I am guessing). The correct way to use a fetcher with a `JSON` cache is:

```
func fetchAllThings(completion: ([AnyObject] -> Void)?) {

    let fetcher = CustomFetcher<JSON>(key: "HELLO")

    let cache = Shared.JSONCache

    cache.fetch(fetcher: fetcher, formatName: "original", failure: {
        error in
        print(error)
        }, success: {
            json in
            completion?(json.array)
    })
}
```

The key here is that I am now using the library's `cache` object to invoke the `Fetcher`.

I hope this helps someone!